# Testing only the constructor of a Class

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

I just want to know is there a way in junit or with the help of any mocking frameworks,to just test the constructor of a class.In a way to just test whether a constructor is invoked like how we test for a method is invoked using verify,can we apply it to constructor.I have seen in many post,where people test the constructor by testing the value of the fields in the class after constructor initialization.
Like

```
Public ClassName{
   private Class x;
   @Inject
   ClassName(Class x){
        this(x.getObjDriver);
     }
    ClassName(Driver d){
       do something...
     }
   public int getValueOfX{
      return x;
 }
```

and in the test class they test this constructor ClassName by calling the construcotr with a argument value for x and then using the getValueOfX method in their assert statement to check the value of x thereby somehow testing the constructor call.
I was thinking doing this in a way not using this approach

is there a way to test the ClassName(Class x) constructor? And also verify in the process the ClassName(Driver d) constructor was also called?

Comment: Just for future reference, if you're testing X, you're not supposed to mock X.

Comment: The goal or a test is to check that a method or constructor does what it is supposed (documented, preferrably) to do. Calling a constructor and verifying that it has been called doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: In my case,in the place of int x in the constructor ,I am Injecting an object and after that I am calling overloaded constructor of the same class from inside this constructor,so I was thinking of unit testing this constructor and was wondering if there is any way of achieving it?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis,thanks ,I wasn't planning of mocking X,I was just giving an example.

Comment: @JBNizet that's only true for unit testing. As soon as you do integration testing, lets say of a book-store, it could possibly make sense to mock a ``Book`` and see if the ``BookFactory`` calls the mocks constructor. Or better to see if the ``BookFactory`` calls the ``Book``s non-mocked-constructor.

Comment: @Waog: that's a different use-case: you're testing a BookFactory, and you check that a Book constructor has been called. The OP wants to test a Book constructor by testing that this constructor has been called.

Comment: Unless you are trying to test a legacy code, do not test implementation - test test behaviour. If you really want - use powermock/spy/verifyNew

Comment: @JBNizet the question is *How to test if a constructor was invoked or not?*. The "use case", is just a misleading example around this question.

Comment: @kan,I understand your views,but when I plan to write a test case for the ClassName(Class x),I am stuck at a point where I need to verify the overloaded constructor (ClassName(Driver d)) is called or not.I am stuck at this point,any help would be appreciated.i will post a mockup solution of what I have tried till now.but it is just a prototype,I haven't tested anything with it

Comment: Why do you need to know if a constructor is called? If it does something, you should assert it using public methods or verify mocks. What does exactly the constructor do? Could you show more meaningful code?

Comment: I tested the public methods it works fine,but I wanted to know whether this type of constructor testing is possible?...My constructor gets a Injected object and call a static method on a Utility class with the injected object as a parameter and this class returns a Connection object which I then use to call the overloaded constructor using THIS ,so I need to write a test case testing whether the constructor was called.